# Using dictionary as a call

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matching

Let's say I have created a dictionary and stored the following keys and values:

bod =  { "Test1" : 12345, "Test2" : 1323242, ... }

Now if I create a new list and have the following values

bof =  ["Test3", "Test1", "Test4", "Test2"]

Is it possible to use the dict variable as a call to match it with the list and assign the values of the matched keys inside a new variable using the following code (pseudo)

```
for l in bof:
    newbof = line.split()
      try:
        newvalues = bod[values]
        print newvalues
```

Comment: can you post the output you want, because at the moment it's hard to understand.

Comment: What is `line`?  Why do you have a `try` with no except/finally?

Comment: What's the problem with the code? And what is that `line` variable?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> bod = { "Test1" : 12345, "Test2" : 1323242 }
>>> bof = ["Test3", "Test1", "Test4", "Test2"]
>>> [bod.get(x) for x in bof]
[None, 12345, None, 1323242]
```

other variations

```
>>> [bod.get(x, 0) for x in bof]
[0, 12345, 0, 1323242]
>>> [bod[x] for x in bof if x in bod]
[12345, 1323242]
```

Comment: i think he does'nt need the None values

Comment: `.get()` will return `None` when there is no corresponding key in the dict. You can ask it to return any other default value, `bod.get(x,0)` for example. This avoid a `KeyError` exception (which is what I suspect the `try` was for in the OP's question).

Comment: @InternalServerError, I think the question doesn't specify either way

Comment: @gnibbler "assign the values of the matched keys inside a new variable", so he wants only matched keys inside the new variable

Answer (score 0):

Can't fully understand your question, to my understanding,

```
newvalues=[]
for i in bof:
  if bod.get(i):
    newvalues.append(bod[i])
print newvalues
```

optimized,

```
newvalues=[bod[i] for i in bof if bod.get(i)]
```

Comment: `if i in bod` is more optimised than `if bod.get(i)`. Also works properly if `bod[i] == 0`

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand:

```
In [325]: bod = { "Test1" : 12345, "Test2" : 1323242}

In [326]: bof = ["Test3", "Test1", "Test4", "Test2"]

In [327]: [bod[i ]for i in bof if i in bod]
Out[327]: [12345, 1323242]
```

or if you want to keep the values not in bod:

```
In [332]: [bod[x] if x in bod else x for x in bof]
Out[332]: ['Test3', 12345, 'Test4', 1323242]
```

or

```
[bod.get(x,x) for x in bof]
Out[333]: ['Test3', 12345, 'Test4', 1323242]
```

Also note that while using `get` is somwhat more concise, using `in` is faster:

```
In [337]: % timeit [bod[x] if x in bod else x for x in bof]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 us per loop

In [338]: % timeit [bod.get(x,x) for x in bof]
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 us per loop
```